# Rig Veda 1-114 final part

Tags: rig-veda

In Rig Veda 1-114

> imā rudrāya tavase kapardine kṣayadvīrāya pra bharāmahe matīḥ |
>   yathā śamasad dvipade catuṣpade viśvaṃ puṣṭaṃghrāme asminnanāturam ||
>   mṛḷā no rudrota no mayas kṛdhi kṣayadvīrāya namasā vidhemate |
>   yacchaṃ ca yośca manurāyeje pitā tadaśyāma tavarudra praṇītiṣu ||
>   aśyāma te sumatiṃ devayajyayā kṣayadvīrasya tava rudra mīḍhvaḥ |
>   sumnāyannid viśo asmākamā carāriṣṭavīrā juhavāma te haviḥ ||
>   tveṣaṃ vayaṃ rudraṃ yajñasādhaṃ vaṅkuṃ kavimavase nihvayāmahe |
>   āre asmad daivyaṃ heḷo asyatu sumatimid vayamasyā vṛṇīmahe ||
>   divo varāhamaruṣaṃ kapardinaṃ tveṣaṃ rūpaṃ namasā nihvayāmahe |
>   haste bibhrad bheṣajā vāryāṇi śarma varma chardirasmabhyaṃ yaṃsat ||
>   idaṃ pitre marutāmucyate vacaḥ svādoḥ svādīyo rudrāya vardhanam |
>   rāsvā ca no amṛta martabhojanaṃ tmane tokāya tanayāya mṛḷa ||
>   mā no mahāntamuta mā no arbhakaṃ mā na ukṣantamuta māna ukṣitam |
>   mā no vadhīḥ pitaraṃ mota mātaraṃ mā naḥ priyāstanvo rudra rīriṣaḥ ||
>   mā nastoke tanaye mā na āyau mā no ghoṣu mā no aśveṣurīriṣaḥ |
>   vīrān mā no rudra bhāmito vadhīrhaviṣmantaḥsadamit tvā havāmahe ||
>   upa te stomān paśupā ivākaraṃ rāsvā pitarmarutāṃ sumnamasme |
>   bhadrā hi te sumatirmṛḷayattamāthā vayamava itte vṛṇīmahe ||
>   āre te ghoghnamuta pūruṣaghnaṃ kṣayadvīra sumnamasme teastu |
>   mṛḷā ca no adhi ca brūhi devādhā ca naḥ śarma yachadvibarhāḥ ||
>   avocāma namo asmā avasyavaḥ śṛṇotu no havaṃ rudro marutvān |
>   tan no ... ||

How it ends after Tan no... ?  Hearing another version seems there is another verse after tan no...

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking transliteration or do you want to know if there is continuation to the mantra?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: The 11th Mantra was left incomplete at this link (https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01114.htm). The OP might be interested in knowing full text.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Okay. Then that should be made clear first and then answered. Because asking for transliteration is off-topic for us. Can you modify the question if you understood it?

Comment: Title modified! Sorry!

Comment: You can refer [sanskritdocuments.org](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/rigveda/e-text.htm) in future for full Rigveda text in Devanagari or in roman transliteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete version is available at [this link](https://www.aurobindo.ru/workings/matherials/rigveda/01/01-114.htm) of Sri Aurobindo Ashrama.

> अवो॑चाम॒ नमो॑ अस्मा अव॒स्यवः॑ शृ॒णोतु॑ नो॒ हवं॑ रु॒द्रो म॒रुत्वा॑न् ।
>
> तन्नो॑ मि॒त्रो वरु॑णो मामहंता॒मदि॑तिः॒ सिंधुः॑ पृथि॒वी उ॒त द्यौः ॥
>
> avocāma ǀ namaḥ ǀ asmai ǀ avasyavaḥ ǀ śṛṇotu ǀ naḥ ǀ havam ǀ rudraḥ ǀ
>   marutvān ǀ
>
> tat ǀ naḥ ǀ mitraḥ ǀ varuṇaḥ ǀ mamahantām ǀ aditiḥ ǀ sindhuḥ ǀ pṛthivī
>   ǀ uta ǀ dyauḥ ǁ

Comment: What is that link? Please name the site too. Is it a PDF or a site of another country? It is uncomfortable to some if they don't know where it will take them.

Comment: Thank You, that's it. For reference i was following exactly that link at https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01114.htm , but i don't understand why the left it incomplete. The final part i was searching is exactly : tat ǀ naḥ ǀ mitraḥ ǀ varuṇaḥ ǀ mamahantām ǀ aditiḥ ǀ sindhuḥ ǀ pṛthivī ǀ uta ǀ dyauḥ ǁ .

Comment: @Sarvabhouma site of another country?

Comment: @Paṇḍyā Yeah. The sites which have different . Some sites are regionally restricted and some add unwanted tracking cookies.What is unclear in that?  This is a site which operates from Russia. So naming a site is not only useful, recommended too.